# Unable to load the downloaded tensorflow model from SciBert Github repository

Tags: nlp, bert-language-model

I am new to using the Bert model and its derivatives. I am trying to use SciBert for my own model and plan to fine-tune it for my specific task. I have downloaded the recommended Tensorflow model from the GitHub repo page of Scibert [here](https://github.com/allenai/scibert).
I tried to load the model the naive way, i.e. by using the SavedModel class but it obviously failed me:

```
import tensorflow as tf
model = tf.keras.models.load_model("scibert_scivocab_uncased")
```

I also tried `TFAutoModel` from HuggingFace's `Transformer` library but it raises an error:

```
OSError: allenai/scibert_scivocab_uncased does not appear to have a file named tf_model.h5 but there is a file for PyTorch weights. Use `from_pt=True` to load this model from those weights.
```

which makes sense as in the documentation it's mentioned that the Pytorch version is made with huggingface, not the tensorflow one. But I want to load a TensorFlow model as I am well versed with TensorFlow.

The model folder which I downloaded from the GitHub repository of [SciBert](https://github.com/allenai/scibert) has the following files contained in it:

1. `bert_config.json`
2. `bert_model.ckpt.data-00000-of-00001`
3. `bert_model.ckpt.index`
4. `bert_model.ckpt.meta`
5. `vocab.txt`
   The documentation on SciBert says to read more about BERT but I can't wrap my head around it and how to load the weights of SciBert into a Bert model (if it is even possible).
   I want a Tensorflow SciBert model to be loaded in my code so that I can work on it. If there is any way I can load the model I downloaded from the repo or any other way, please let me know.